# Python >= comparison operator throwing syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement

It seems my `if else` statement throws a syntax error. I've read up on how `if` statements should be written (and the other `if else` statements in my script work with no issues) so I am not sure why there's an issue.

```
if small_wh <= 5.0:
    emColor = discord.Color.red
elif small_wh <= 15.0 and >= 5.1:
    emColor = discord.Color.orange
```

The `>=` (in the `elif` statement) is where it states the syntax error is.

Comment: You have to repeat the variable in the second condition: `small_wh <= 15.0 and small_wh >= 5.1`

Answer (score 1):

The second comparison of you `elif` statement isn’t comparing anything to 5.1.

```
elif small_wh <= 15.0 and small_wh >= 5.1:
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compare `5.1` with some value, not `and` word, i.e. do:

```
elif small_wh <= 15.0 and small_wh >= 5.1:
```

or using python capability to combine comparisons you can do::

```
elif 5.1 <= small_wh <= 15.0:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if small_wh <= 5.0:
   emColor = discord.Color.red
elif small_wh <= 15.0 and small_wh >= 5.1:
   emColor = discord.Color.orange
```